# What key combo did I just press? Screen res dropped and some programs look bad

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I have pressed something accidentally and every program just looked turned hideous, after a bit I found the resolution dropped to 1366x768 instead of the native full HD. Even after changing back to full HD the contents of Double Commander and NotePad++ but not the their menus looked incredibly bad, apparently a log out and log back was necessary because scaling have dropped and didn't reapply after resetting the screen resolution.

So, how did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've triggered a Windows "Accessibility" feature. See [Windows keyboard shortcuts for accessibility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13810/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-accessibility) for all shortcuts, but most likely it was <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>, magnifier. To get out of magnified  view, first be sure that's the issdue by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> again, and then pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.